# Use Burp Suite Community edition to track traffic over VPN and proxy

Tags: vpn, burp, foxyproxy

my application is accessible only on VPN (I use Cisco VPN client) and I need to have proxy enabled in my chrome browser  using Foxy Proxy.
Only after I connect to VPN and enable Foxy Proxy, I am able to access my application.

How can I monitor the traffic of my app via Burp?
What should I use - Burp build in browser or external browser?
Can you please point me in the right direction? Currently I have no clue about where/how to start.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I eventually did:

1. So I set up the browser with Foxy Proxy to point to Burp
   (127.0.0.1:8080)
2. Set in my Proxy Settings of Windows OS to use proxy pointing to my VPN IP
3. Set in the Burp the User Options tab in the Upstream Proxy Servers the IP of my VPN as well
4. Needed to configure self signed certificate with burp (their docs is a great resource)

So this way all my browser traffic goes through the local burp and he than goes through my VPN and I can successfully open my app page and intercept the traffic.
Also there is a hint just to filter/track traffic from specific site:

- Target tab > define the Target Scope to be the URL of your app
- Proxy tab > Options tab > in Intercept Client Requests check the one with the "And URL In target scope"

Comment: Test it. Got Unknown Host