# How to use Burp Suite and VPN simultaneously on a Kali Linux VM?

Tags: proxy, virtual-machine, vpn, burp

I don't know what to configure in order to achieve such effect.

(Host: Windows10)(VMware)(Network mode: bridged network)
Okay so here's the condition: I'm in China right now, I'm on a Windows 10 machine which has a Kali VM in it. Burp Suite and FoxyProxy work successfully. But I'm in China so in order to access the internet I need to turn on my VPN, and this is where the issue kicks in. Now what I'm trying is to use both Burp and VPN on my VM at the same time. I have two VPNs and both of them work fine (Proton VPN, and I'm using another one not famous. I can change to Proton because people are more familiar with it.) Please give **DETAILED(please!!)** solutions and advice because I'm a noob sorry.
Again I'm pretty sure I have nothing wrong with common configurations, Burp Suite works fine with FoxyProxy when I'm accessing websites that are not banned in China, so merely the cooperation with VPN is needed to be solved.
A million thanks if anyone may give me a piece of advice, this problems has been haunted me for days and I'm not allowed to have much free time to learn hacking. Eager for advice, thank you!!!!!!!!! >:] (Related advice I found: [Use Burp Suite Community edition to track traffic over VPN and proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70162540/use-burp-suite-community-edition-to-track-traffic-over-vpn-and-proxy)) appreciate